# How to format a currency string in Laravel view?

Tags: php, laravel

(I'm on a windows server and can't use money_format).

I'm trying to use NumberFormatter inside a Laravel view. I want to format the value inside the view directly rather than format inside the controller.

php_intl is enabled.

When called, I get the following error: `Object of class NumberFormatter could not be converted to string (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\.eclipseproduct\rsst\resources\views\products.blade.php)`

```
{!!$cash = new NumberFormatter("en-US", NumberFormatter::CURRENCY)!!}
    @foreach($products as $product)
        <tr>
            <form action="{{url('/order/add')}}" method="post" data-ajax="false">
                {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <input type = "hidden" name = "pID" value = '{{$product->pID}}'/>
                <td>{{$product->pName}}</td>
                <td>{{$product->pBrand}}</td>
                <td>{{$product->pCurrentType}}</td>
                <td>{{$product->pVoltage}}V</td>

                <td>${{ $cash->formatCurrency( $product->pPrice , "USD") }}</td>
                <td><input type ="text" name="qty"/>
                <input type = "submit" value="submit"></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: check BankFacil/vanilla-masker , it should help you

Comment: What is BankFacil/vanilla-masker, @AchrafKhouadja?

Comment: [This? ](https://github.com/BankFacil/vanilla-masker) An interesting possible solution, but I'm on a tight deadline and figuring out how to use this, and then Grunt, much less use it with Laravel, might be a bit much to ask for.

Comment: A pure Javascript element that evaluates the value would be a good workaround, but long term I expect further variations on this problem, so an accepted answer needs to deal with the issue in PHP directly.

Comment: Perhaps it should be cast to a string first? Try casting it first?  `$cash->formatCurrency( (string)$product->pPrice , "USD")`

Comment: @camelCase Nope, just tried, that's not the problem.

Comment: What datatype is `$product->pPrice`? Float, Integer...?

Comment: It comes from SQL Server, probably decimal though I can't look it up right now. I would expect Laravel to treat a "decimal" value as double, but that's something I can't say for sure.

Comment: It's quite odd that it throws this error then. I would imagine just passing `$product->pPrice` properly displays the data from the database, albeit not formatted. The error points towards the issue of passing an `object` into the method but from what you suspect, it's not an `object`.

Comment: Is there a way to definitively test the type of the object?

Comment: Yep, you can do `gettype($product->pPrice)` which returns a string of the variable type. Pretty handy function to use for issues like this.